# ndb.OR operation in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I am Working on project where I need to do ndb.OR operation in Descending Order but for below code I am getting error like this:

BadRequestError: The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied.  In your query the first sort property is TestNo but the inequality filter is on Math

```
class StudentMarks(ndb.Model):
    Math = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    Science = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    English = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    Social = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    TestNo = ndb.IntegerProperty()

@classmethod
def queryData(cls):
    return cls.query(ndb.OR(ndb.OR(cls.Math > 0, cls.Science > 0),
                     ndb.OR(cls.English > 0 , cls.Social > 0))).order(-cls.TestNo)
```

Is there any other way to implement this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without understanding your use case, I can come up with two ways.

1. Sort in memory after the fact - this won't scale if you have thousands of entities.
2. Use and AND clause and with TestNo as the first inequality filter (ie `TestNo > -1` for instance) and the OR the second part of the AND clause.

Another approach may be changing or adding to the data stored so that you can use equality filters.  It seems you are looking for various combinations of Math, Science, English etc.. that have a value greater than 0.  Consider adding a ComputedProperty that stores a boolean of true of Math, Science etc is > 0, and false if == 0, then you could rewrite your query to 
something like the following.  (I am using property name like hasMath for the computed property)

Computed Property would look like

```
hasMath = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.Math > 0)
```

Query would be

```
cls.query(ndb.OR(ndb.OR(cls.hasMath == True, cls.hasScience == True),
                 ndb.OR(cls.hasEnglish == True , cls.hasSocial == True))).order(-cls.TestNo)
```

Looking at your query further you could reduce the computed property to a single property to meet your query requirement.

```
 hasClass = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.Math > 0 or self.Science > 0 or self.English > 0 or self.Social > 0)
```

The your query would be

```
 cls.query(cls.hasClass == True).order(-cls.TestNo)
```

Assuming this is the only query of this kind that you want to perform, this last option will be the best performing and least expensive in terms of indexes.

Comment: Do you mean like this:                                             return cls.query((ndb.AND(cls.TestNo > 0), ndb.OR(ndb.OR(cls.Math > 0, cls.Science > 0),ndb.OR(cls.English > 0 , cls.Social > 0)))).order(-cls.TestNo)

Comment: Yes something like that. Not sure if it will give you what your want, but worth a shot, as now you can specify your required sort order

Comment: But it might be worth revisiting your use case and how you are storing data.  Because you may be able reformulate your filter into using equality filters. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Another obvious question why OR'ing multiple OR' statements.  Essentially the query would be on OR statement, or as per the computed Property suggestion a single computed property that stores True if hany of the classes has a value > 1.

Comment: I even want the integer value of each properties like: math = 50, science = 30, English = 44 etc in descending order of TestNo as a query result.

Comment: You already have the integer values, the computed properties are in  addition.